# JPA can't delete a ManyToMany without removing both side

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have an entity with a ManyToMany on itself:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Volunteer {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Volunteer.class, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Volunteer> validPartners = new HashSet<>();

}
```

The problem is when I delete a `Volunteer` I want to delete the object and relation to other `Volunteer`, but not delete the linked `Volunteers` entities.

I try all types of Cascade but none of them works, if I use `REMOVE/ALL` then the association is removed but also the linked entity, and when I use other types I have a constraint error.

What should I do to remove only the association and the current entity when I remove from db ?

I already try to do a `PreRemove` like this:

```
 @PreRemove
 private void removePartners() {
     for (Volunteer v : validPartners) {
         v.getValidPartners().remove(this);
     }
 }
```

But it doesn't change anything, I always have a constraint error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Intégrité référentielle violation de contrainte: "FKSGEJ479ESPKJJ86G17OVSLGJB: PUBLIC.VOLUNTEER_VALID_PARTNERS FOREIGN KEY(VALID_PARTNERS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.VOLUNTEER(ID) (X'e8825d7b76f5420aa1e1a36b06bca65a')"
```

Comment: I think that you'll need to stop cascading from reaching second Volunteer by using `@ManyToMany(..., cascade={PERSIST, DETACH})` BR

Comment: Even using these cascade I still have the Constraint violation :/ I really don't understand how to handle this

Comment: Setting up a test for this, coming back to you soon. BR

Comment: OK, tests are added below. Can you run these on your side? BR

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right; when deleting a Volunteer instance, are you going to delete more instances in addition to the selected one? If yes, may it be that relationship logically is one-to-many instead of many-to-many?

Comment: When I delete a Volunteer I only want to delete the current entity and the associations, not the other side entity.

Comment: Good to hear. Then my last update for first test should do the trick: BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added some tests for this in order to dig into this with some common code. First test is currently passing.

---

Conclusion after reading misc articles and after some disussion with OP: The case here is a uni-directional relation from class Volunteer to other instances of class Volunteer, and OP wants to delete an instance in the not-owning end of the relation.

Deleting relation before deleting entity, seems to be best practice. This is shown in test `deleteVolunteer_deleteRelationFirst` below.

---

My repo implementation

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.volunteer;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface VolunteerRepository extends JpaRepository<Volunteer, UUID> {
}
```

Test class

```
package no.mycompany.myapp.volunteer;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
public class VolunteerRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    VolunteerRepository volunteerRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void cleanup() {
        volunteerRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteVolunteer_deleteRelationFirst() {
        var persistedOne = testEntityManager.persist(createValidVolunteer());
        var persistedTwo = testEntityManager.persist(createValidVolunteer());
        var persistedThree = testEntityManager.persist(createValidVolunteer());
        var persistedFour = testEntityManager.persist(createValidVolunteer());
        assertThat(persistedOne.getId()).isNotEqualTo(persistedTwo.getId());

        var inDb1 = volunteerRepository.getOne(persistedOne.getId());
        var inDbToDelete = volunteerRepository.getOne(persistedTwo.getId());
        var inDb3 = volunteerRepository.getOne(persistedThree.getId());
        var inDb4 = volunteerRepository.getOne(persistedFour.getId());

        inDb1.getValidPartners().add(inDbToDelete);
        volunteerRepository.save(inDb1);

        inDbToDelete.getValidPartners().add(inDb3);
        volunteerRepository.save(inDbToDelete);

        inDb3.getValidPartners().add(inDb4);
        volunteerRepository.save(inDb3);

        // verify that valid partners count equals to 1
        persistedOne = testEntityManager.find(Volunteer.class, inDb1.getId());
        assertThat(persistedOne.getValidPartners().size()).isEqualTo(1);

        inDbToDelete.getValidPartners().clear();
        inDb1.getValidPartners().remove(inDbToDelete);
        volunteerRepository.save(inDb1);

        // verify that valid partners count now equals to 0
        persistedOne = testEntityManager.find(Volunteer.class, inDb1.getId());
        assertThat(persistedOne.getValidPartners().size()).isEqualTo(0);

        // verify that we still have the second instance in db
        persistedTwo = testEntityManager.find(Volunteer.class, inDbToDelete.getId());
        assertThat(persistedTwo).isNotNull();

        volunteerRepository.delete(inDbToDelete);

        // verify instance is deleted
        persistedTwo = testEntityManager.find(Volunteer.class, inDbToDelete.getId());
        assertThat(persistedTwo).isNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteVolunteer_notDeleteRelationFirst() {
        var persistedOne = testEntityManager.persist(createValidVolunteer());
        var persistedTwo = testEntityManager.persist(createValidVolunteer());

        var inDb1 = volunteerRepository.getOne(persistedOne.getId());
        var inDb2 = volunteerRepository.getOne(persistedTwo.getId());

        inDb1.getValidPartners().add(inDb2);
        volunteerRepository.save(inDb1);

        // verify that valid partners count equals to 1
        persistedOne = testEntityManager.find(Volunteer.class, inDb1.getId());
        assertThat(persistedOne.getValidPartners().size()).isEqualTo(1);

        volunteerRepository.delete(inDb2);

        // verify that valid partners count now equals to 0
        persistedOne = testEntityManager.find(Volunteer.class, inDb1.getId());
        assertThat(persistedOne.getValidPartners().size()).isEqualTo(0); // WILL FAIL
    }

    private static Volunteer createValidVolunteer() {
        var volunteer = new Volunteer();
        volunteer.setEmail("a@b.c");
        return volunteer;
    }
}
```

I'm using same impl for Volunteer class as you. Running this with H2 in-memory database.

Comment: The test pass but the process is a bit different from mine, here you delete manually the associations before deleting the entity. So I should remove the associations, then save the object, and then delete it?

Comment: Let's get an overview over the options we have to choose from. Many-to-many and cascading is a little bit tricky, need to conference a little bit with doc first.

Comment: Deleting association manually is the only solution I found currently but idk if it's the good one

Comment: I also think that is the safest solution, but I will look a little more into this and let you know my findings. BR

Comment: @Jessy: Seems from misc doc that deleting the relation before deleting the entity is still best practice. Joyeux Noël BR

Comment: Hey, do you know if it's possible to use a @Query with an INNER JOIN in order to delete on multiple tables at the same moment. I now need to delete an entity which have ManyToMany on an object which itself have ManyToMany, it's not very practical to have to delete each association for each level of children manually

Comment: @Jessy: Updated my first test where Volunteer instance to delete has children. Look for `inDbToDelete.getValidPartners().clear();` in my test. So, if I got the problem correct, one line of code should fix the issue.